# Increasing the accuracy of the fit when using LinearModelFit

Tags: numerics, fitting

Question: is it possible to increase the accuracy of the `BestFit` property for `LinearModelFit`?

I have code that uses `LinearModelFit` and the `BestFit` property to return the best fitting slope of a list of data. But, a peculiar result I've ran into is very slightly negative slope as a result for data where the slope is 0.

Example:

```
{{Log[10], Log[2]}, {Log[20], Log[2]}, {Log[30], Log[2]},{Log[40], Log[2]}, {Log[50], Log[2]}}
```

produces

```
7.411988753*10^-21
```

for the slope, even though we can see that the exact slope is 0.

Here is the context:

```
For[j = 1, j <= Length[pointsList], j++,
  measureData = Map[{Log[1/#], Log[BoxCount[pointsList[[j]], #]]} &, scaleList];
  line = LinearModelFit[measureData, x, x];
  AppendTo[dimensionList, Coefficient[line["BestFit"], x, 1]]];
```

`pointsList` is just a list of lists of points; `scaleList = {1/10, 1/20, 1/30, 1/40, 1/50}`. The example I shared was one list from `pointsList` and its corresponding element in `dimensionList`.

So, is there a way to increase the accuracy of linear model fit? Alternatively, I could emplace an `If` expression to solve the best fitting slopes I can solve algebraicly, but I was hoping this wasn't necessary.

Comment: add the option `...,WorkingPrecision->100]` to `LinearModelFit[...]` to have a 100 digits working precision.

Comment: try also `...WorkingPrecision->Infinity]` to have exact arithmetic

Comment: This didn't seem to make the guess for the slope more correct, just closer to the intended guess. Using infinity left me with a large expression saturated with logs instead of a slope of 0.

Comment: What is `BoxCount`?

Comment: Try `Coefficient[line["BestFit"] // Chop`

Comment: I can only assume you'll have rational estimates for the coefficients (or rational multiples of $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$, etc.) for "textbook" examples.  When the slope is exactly some rational number you'll usually also have (but not in your example) a non-zero error variance.  If the error variance is not zero, then having "infinite precision" for an estimate is a bit overkill.  It all depends on why you need exact estimates.  I think the best approach is what @andre recommended.

Comment: But note that if the dependent variable always a function of integer counts, then the assumption of normally distributed errors is certainly not "exact".  You would likely be better off using `GeneralizedLinearModelFit` which can appropriately allow for functions of integer dependent variables.

Comment: When you tried @andre 's suggestion and had a "large expression saturated with logs", did you try "Simplify" or "FullSimplify"?  If the estimated slope is really zero, it will simplify to zero.  That suggestion certainly works with your first example.  Sharing the example that appears not to work would be essential to determine the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The concern raised in the OP makes no effective difference.  The range of the independent variable is `Log[50] - Log[10]`, so the difference in the predicted value of the dependent variable is at most

```
(7.411988753*10^-21 (Log[50] - Log[10])
```

When added to `Log[2]` it makes no difference (literally zero) at machine precision, due to the way floating-point numbers work:

```
(7.411988753*10^-21 (Log[50] - Log[10]) + Log[2]) - Log[2]
(*  0.  *)
```

The nonzero value of the slope is most likely due to rounding or truncation error in the numerical procedure used to estimate the "best" fit.  But this error is negligible in this case.

Note: This is merely an explanation of the numerics of the problem, which seemed to be the basis for the issue raised. More important issues related to how to model -- some raised in the comments -- are nearly impossible to address, since the data provided seemed manufactured simply to illustrate the error in the slope.